# Изменить голос за принятый/правильный ответ

Tags: поддержка, ответы, принятые-ответы

Можно ли изменить свой голос за принятый/верный ответ?
Заметил в одном вопросе, что принятый ответ был изменен. Как это делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто кликнуть галочку для принятия на другом ответе - она снимется с текущего принятого и поставится новому.

Comment: я думал, что так нельзя делать

Comment: @Александр, почему же? Вполне может появиться более хороший ответ, либо оказаться, что у принятого есть критичный недостаток, который по началу не был замечен.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать :)